# How to prevent gnome Network Settings GUI from overriding my network settings?

Tags: networking, 18.04, gnome, network-manager, settings

I wish to simply set a Static IP in **/etc/network/interfaces** file. I'm used to doing this successfully on boxes without a GUI.

But now I am using "Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver" with GNOME and the Network Settings set in the GUI are overriding my /etc/network/interfaces file settings. How can I prevent this?

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces no longer controls networking in 18.04. It is managed by netplan. I suggest that you transfer your settings there. https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: @chili555 not 100% accurate. The /etc/netplan/*.yaml file can be set to use NetworkManager, just like the good old days.

Comment: Perhaps I should expand my too brief comment above. In any Desktop installation, Network Manager is the preferred and generally quite effective method to manage networking. If one must, and few of us ever will, manage networking using manual methods, in Ubuntu 17.10 and later, `/etc/network/interfaces` will be ineffective and ignored as it has been replaced by netplan: https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: In server installations, where Network Manager is not installed by default, netplan is required unless one wishes to install ifup/down, remove all netplan yaml files and then populate `/etc/network/interfaces`. It is a somewhat daunting task to revert to methods that will soon be obsolete. @heynnema

Comment: @chili555  In desktop machines, the use of NetworkManager and its GUI interface is much easier for users, esp if they frequently use wireless with different SSIDs. Netplan can be set to default to NetworkManager... or set to use Netplan exclusively... but in cli mode only. In servers, netplan is the default. Server admins must learn the somewhat fussy .yaml scripting, and many times have difficulty getting them to work as expected.

Comment: @chili555 re:"n Ubuntu 17.10 and later, /etc/network/interfaces will be ineffective and ignored as it has been replaced by netplan". Not entirely true. If netplan is set to default to NetworkManager, the /etc/network/interfaces file, and all of the old NetworkManager techniques, work as they always did. Netplan didn't replace NetworkManager (yet), it's just an alternative (unless you're on a server). And, along with renaming network device names, netplan kind of sucks for the average user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88627/discussion-between-chili555-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to use the `network-manager`GUI you mentioned itself to set up a static IP. However if you still wish to do it via file **/etc/network/interfaces**, then you have to disable network manager by

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```

[Here is a link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-a-static-ip-address-on-debian-linux) for more details

Comment: Thanks. I only want to do it because I require scripts when interfaces come up, but it looks like this is possible with the NetworkManager anyway.

Comment: Well if it helped, consider upvoting the answer :)

Comment: @thephoenix01 if you stop/disable NetworkManager, the GUI becomes useless. NetworkManager shouldn't interfere with /etc/network/interfaces... they've coexisted since forever.